# Access Time Capsule's files from iPhone

Tags: iphone, time-capsule, afp

Is it possible to access Yime Capsule's files from iPhone? On my Mac I'm simply connecting to `afp://10.0.1.1/` and I have my data.

But on my iPhone, when I try to connect (e.g. from Safari) I get an error.

Is it possible to browse AFP servers from iOS? Or maybe there's a way to enable `WebDAV` on it?

Comment: Is this about AFP specifically?  Or would using SSH be OK?

Comment: I have a disk connected to my TC via USB. I want e.g. play music or watch movies on it. I can do it on Mac, but not on my iPhone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to access server shares from Apple's iOS. iOS does not have a Samba or AFP client, and thus, cannot handle these requests.

Time Capsule uses modified AirPort Extreme firmware and supports AFP and SMB file-sharing protocols.

Unfortunately, this is the extent of your capabilities of accessing files on Time Capsule from iOS. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

[Oplayer HD](https://itunes.apple.com/app/oplayer-hd-media-player-for/id373236724?mt=8) is a great app. I use it just for watching videos of any format and last time I used it I saw it also had automatically connected to my data folder on the time capsule. Meaning I can download movies onto the time capsule and then watch them from my IPad. super convenient. Oplayer doesn't open every file, but more than you would think.

Answer (score -1):

Use file browser on iTunes it'll do the job

Answer (score -2):

It is possible with 3rd party software.

There are dozens of apps in the App Store for browsing afp/smb network shares, including Time Capsule internal drive.
Some apps focus on video, some focus on documents, some trying to do both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Instead of sending people to the Store to search for themselves, can you list at least one or two apps which actually do help here?

Comment: I thought about that, and decided to not link any apps. a) I'm not an expert on the subject, because I don't own all the apps in question. b) the two I use are paid apps, and I'm not 100% happy with them c) it's fairly easy to do a search for "afp video" or "smb documents" and find a bunch of free apps to try d) http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3495/whats-a-good-iphone-app-that-will-let-me-view-files-on-my-network/3559#3559